# Can I use assume a Normal Distribution to calculate a Confidence Interval for multiple random variables with different means and std each?

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, confidence-interval, multivariate-statistical-analysis

Let's say, I've a table with a list of trips I need to make this week
and I want to calculate a confidence interval for the average trip duration time
for all the trips I'll make in the week.

| Var | Trip name | mean (minutes) | std (minutes) | Trips scheduled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Home-University | 15 | 3 | 5 |
| B | University-Home | 19 | 4 | 3 |
| C | University-Work | 5 | 1 | 2 |
| D | Work-Home | 20 | 7 | 2 |

I know that
`E[X+Y] = E[X] + E[Y]`
And `Var[X+Y] = Var[X] + Var[Y]`

So the average trip duration given the data in the table must be:
$$ \mu_{trip\ duration} = \frac{5(A.mean) + 3(B.mean) + 2(C.mean) + 2(D.mean)}{12}$$

And a similar formulation for the variance, but If I want to create a confidence interval should I assume that this distribution (the sum of all the trips) follows a normal distribution and then multiply the standard error by the z-score? or is it wrong to assume a normal distribution?

Comment: I'm no exp4rt, but the sum of normals is normal with mean and variance like you say. See wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables

Comment: Thanks @coffeemath, the link you shared has this article [Algebra_of_random_variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_random_variables) as reference and is also very useful :)